# My acer has started to wilt, after a period of strong growth

Tags: maple, wilt, japanese-maple, topsoil

My 4 year old acer has suddenly started to wilt after a strong bloom. It has been relatively warm for this time of year (15c/59f) and has recently had a new layer of multi purpose compost added to the top layer of the soil, followed by a good amount of water.
I cant remember if this is normal in the  early stages of the bloom, or if I should be taking measures to help it get back to looking a little healthier?[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in? Have you had lots of dry warm weather and/or frosty nights?

Comment: I'm in the UK. Yes absolutely. The weather has been warmer than usual over the last week or so, and we've had frost the last few nights as well! Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered if you were in the UK (as I am). We have indeed, after a very wet winter, had some very dry and warm weather - your  Acer probably needs a good soak, especially if you are in the south/south east or east of the UK, so if you have a hose, let it trickle at the base for an hour or 3, moving it 3 or 4 times to cover the root zone near the base. Either that or run a sprinkler for at least  an hour, preferably two, on it, but wait till its in shade if you do that. I have been running the sprinkler last week and most of this week so far in our large gardens here in West London, and still it's quite dry, to the point where our clay soil has large cracks in it.

If its got really dry, you may find some leaves shrivel and fall off - don't worry too much, keep it well watered as necessary and more should arrive later on.

Comment: Your advice has been very helpful indeed thank you. I've given a good soaking late in the evening yesterday. Not too sure the heat of today will of helped, but at least I know I'm not chasing a lost cause. Thank you very much!